# Technomancer's Dragon Hoard - What to do with all the credits?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4, treasure, technomancer

## Problem

I noticed that as a Technomancer I end up with a hoard of credits and I'am having trouble figuring out how to spend it. I have High Lifestyle, A fair safehouse with luxury level security, Some doberman, and some Flying Eye (Micro) flying drones (Which any time I try to use I get randomly "disconnected" from which makes no sense to me considering they are about an inch big. But that's not the point here.)

## Question

I am asking for ideas of what it would be good to use my credits on.

Comment: Find a bunch of wannabe runners you like the look of, supply them with cyberware, and guns, and fetishes, support, and pay for their rent and security and safehouses - and never let them forget that they *owe* you...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem as a Technomancer: you are basically a Hacker who doesn't have to buy a good commlink or great programs (and as an Alias follower, I couldn't even spend on a Lifestyle). You have two options there:

### If you don't want to do drones:

Buy huge guns. Buy a huge war, and don't worry about encumbrance. You can even consider "burning" one point of Resonance to buy some bioware/cyberware (especially if your drain is based on Logic..)

### If you want to do drones:

Well... Drones. Lots of them. Have drones everywhere. An invisible flying drone 1km over the city, with a mounted sniper. A monster inconspicuous car in the street, with a boosted commlink and System and a mortar. A dozen Arachne drones with mounted Uzis in your backpack. An armored Horseman that you rig from the inside.

### If you REALLY have a lot of money.

Buy a cyborg. Add mods. Give it big guns. Rig it from home.

Comment: I really like the idea of "An invisible flying drone 1km over the city, with a mounted sniper." how ever there is currently a gentlemen's agreement in place about sniper rifles. "Sniper cold war" We don't use them and the DM will not use them. (on us)

Comment: are Arachne drones small? and how much does it cost to add invisible to a flying drone? and do you need command flying thing to be able to jump a drone?

Comment: One of my favorite characters was a rigger who controlled a cybernetic twin for kung fu action.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that there is nothing wrong with buying gifts for your friends that will make them more effective.

Also, I believe it is only a house rule, but I have known GMs to let you buy karma (in story justification was that it was buying effective training.)

Comment: very interesting on the buying karma thing!